# Unable to execute Postgresql commands with python in seperate docker containers

Tags: python, database, postgresql, docker, psycopg2

I have this setup 
1) **Docker Container Server** running postgresql image in background created with command 
`docker run --name post2 -d postgres` 
2) **Client Docker Container** running ubuntu with python running psycopg2 
My Postgresql container is exposed on ip address 172.7.0.2:5432. I'm able to communicate with the server when enter command `curl 172.17.0.2:5432` in my client container

The **Docker Container Server** logs `LOG:invalid length of startup packet`. I do not send any message packets but it shows communication with server.

I'm running these commands in python2 shell in **Client Docker Container**.

```
>>> conn = psycopg2.connect(host='172.17.0.2', port='5432', user='postgres', database='yoman')
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("CREATE TABLE test (id serial PRIMARY KEY, num integer, data varchar);")

>>> conn1 = psycopg2.connect(host='172.17.0.2', port='5432', user='postgres', database='template1')
```

`yeoman` and `template1` are precreated databases in the server which I created. 
I believe its successfully communicating with server because it recognizes that the database `asdf` does not exist as stack trace below.

```
 >>> conn = psycopg2.connect(host='172.17.0.2', port='5432', user='postgres', database='asdfd')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
        conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
    psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "asdfd" does not exist
```

My problem is my commands are not executing in the database. 
I run the code below to create a table called "test" but nothing happens. Also no error is thrown. 
`cur.execute("CREATE TABLE test (id serial PRIMARY KEY, num integer, data varchar);")`

My Postgres database which shows no tables.

```
postgres=# \l
                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 yoman     | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
(4 rows)

postgres=# \c yoman
You are now connected to database "yoman" as user "postgres".
yoman=# \d
No relations found.
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Thanks.

Comment: You just need to commit the transaction `conn.commit()`

Comment: my goodness ...
@warmoverflow thank you very much. From the docs, it showed data could exist in the db without the conn.commit(). http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html got confused there.

Would you happen to know why is the docs different? Is it because I'm running postgres in a docker container?